# Error when binding data into gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview

I have trouble binding data from web service into my web application's grid view.

Error:

> A data item was not found in the container. The container must either implement IDataItemContainer, or have a property named DataItem.

Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlEvent.DataSource = en.getCategory();
        ddlEvent.DataTextField = "category";
        ddlEvent.DataValueField = "categoryId";
        ddlEvent.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void ddlEvent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventView.DataSource = en.getEvent(ddlEvent.SelectedValue.ToString());
    eventView.DataBind();
}
```

the method getEvent requires a string parameter to retrieve data on specific fields.
For ddlEvent's DataValueField, there's only 1, 2 and 3.

Here's my web service:

http://b0ac8787bb664948b10d5374441ce99d.cloudapp.net/MQEntertainment.asmx

The problem is in the web service, I input the parameter '1' in getEvent method, i do have an output. But when it is invoked into my web application, the error is shown.

I tried to replace "ddlEvent.SelectedValue.ToString()" with a string "1", there is an output. I tried to use "Trim()" but it doesn't help at all.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

P.S. Let me know if I miss out any relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getEvent` returns `eventList[]` according to the web service. The problem is the returned `eventList[]` may contain some null elements, so you have to remove the null elements first before binding to `eventView`. This code works for me:

```
protected void ddlEvent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventList[] events = en.getEvent(ddlEvent.SelectedValue);
    eventView.DataSource = events.Where(x => x != null);
    eventView.DataBind();
}
```